# How to filter a database on other data

Tags: r

I have a dataset df that looks like this:

[image]

and another two datasets that look like this:

Dataset A:

[image]

Dataset B:

[image]

I want to build a data `C<-df %>% keep (name(df) %in% A$Data)` and then check if B$Data show up in C or not. what should I do?

Sample data can be get from:

```
df<-structure(list(cy3.CSV = c("cy3.CSV", NA, NA), cy6.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", 
"cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), dlt.CSV = c("dlt.CSV", NA, NA), dm.CSV = c("dm.CSV", 
NA, NA), dov.CSV = c("dov.CSV", "dov_1.CSV", NA), dov_1.CSV = c("dov_1.CSV", 
NA, NA), ds.CSV = c("ds.CSV", "ds_1.CSV", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

A<-structure(list(Data = c("cy6.CSV", "dov.CSV", "ds.CSV"), match = c(3, 
2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

B<-structure(list(Data = c("cy3.CSV", "dlt.CSV", "dm.CSV", "dov_1.CSV"
), match = c(1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can place the dataset in a `list` and then do it in a loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(list(A, B), ~ .x %>%
           mutate(in_df = Data %in% union(colnames(df), unlist(df))))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Data    match in_df
#  <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>
#1 cy6.CSV     3 TRUE 
#2 dov.CSV     2 TRUE 
#3 ds.CSV      2 TRUE 

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Data      match in_df
#  <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>
#1 cy3.CSV       1 TRUE 
#2 dlt.CSV       1 TRUE 
#3 dm.CSV        1 TRUE 
#4 dov_1.CSV     1 TRUE
```

---

Based on the comments, may be this helps

```
C <- df %>%
        select_if(~ any(. %in% A$Data))

# dplyr version >= 1.0
C %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., is.na(.), intersect(B$Data, .)[1])))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  cy6.CSV  dov.CSV   ds.CSV  
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
#1 cy1.CSV  dov.CSV   ds.CSV  
#2 cy24.CSV dov_1.CSV ds_1.CSV
#3 cy6.CSV  dov_1.CSV <NA>    

# dplyr version < 1.0

C %>% 
   mutate_all( ~ replace(., is.na(.), intersect(B$Data, .)[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. :) however this is not something i expected. I just updated the post with a picture. Sorry for the poor drawing. Hopefully I explained my question in a better way now.

Comment: @Stataq Thank you for the comment.  I am a bit confused with that picture.  Do you want to create the 'C' table from 'A' and 'B'?

Comment: I want to create c by `c <-df %>% sth like  (name(df) %in% A$Data)`. Basically keep  the variables from df  if it is in A$Data. Then later check if B$Data can be find in C.

Comment: @Stataq Do you need to find the column names i.e. `df %>% select_if(~ any(. %in% A$Data))`

Comment: @Stataq I have a doubt for the B data.  `df %>% select_if(~ any(. %in% B$Data))` returns 4 columns.  Why is it that you are only selecting `dov_1.CSV`  While for A, all the 3 are selected

Comment: B is not check with df.  I want to check whether B$Data  can be find in anywhere within C, not col names, but the observations within each col.

Comment: @Stataq So, `C <- df %>% select_if(~ any(. %in% A$Data))` ?

Comment: Yes, this part is correct! :) We are now need to find out step 2. I updated the picture, hopefully that can help.

Comment: I tried and get error`could not find function "across"`. Is this from `dplyr`? I did call `library(dplyr)` before i tried.

Comment: @Stataq Perhaps you have dplyr version < 1.0.  Can you try the update

Comment: Yes, I have 0.8.5. Tried to updated it but keep getting error message. :( Don't know why.

Comment: @Stataq you can use `mutate_all` which should work on that

Comment: Thanks. Yes, C is what I need. what should I do to identify dov_1 for step 2?

Comment: @Stataq You may paste with 'new' or something i.e. `C %>% 
   mutate_all( ~ replace(., is.na(.), paste0(intersect(B$Data, .)[1], "_new")))`

Comment: Can we modify `intersect(B$Data, C?)` in someway so we can get a list of B$data that is/are intersect with C?

Comment: @Stataq Yes, in that case you can use `C %>%     mutate_all( ~ replace(., is.na(.), toString(paste0(intersect(B$Data, .), "_new"))))`

Comment: I mean Lst1 <-`intersect(B$Data, C?)`, view(Lst1)=> "dov_1.CSV". something i can get `Lst1`.

Comment: For that you need to `unlist(C)` i.e. `intersect(B$Data, unlist(C))` because 'C" is a data.frame

Comment: Wonderful!!!  That is what I want! Thanks million. :)

Answer (score 3):

Convert your `df` to a vector, making sure to preserve column names. Then, check for the condition using `%in%`:

```r
m <- c(colnames(df), unlist(df))

B$in_df <- B$Data %in% m
A$in_df <- A$Data %in% m

A
#>      Data match in_df
#> 1 cy6.CSV     3  TRUE
#> 2 dov.CSV     2  TRUE
#> 3  ds.CSV     2  TRUE

B
#>        Data match in_df
#> 1   cy3.CSV     1  TRUE
#> 2   dlt.CSV     1  TRUE
#> 3    dm.CSV     1  TRUE
#> 4 dov_1.CSV     1  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks so much for prompt reply. However I know A and B in df (A and B are built from df)  I want to build C only has variables that  are in B; and then check whether any B$Data show up in C as value. For my example, we need to find Dov_1.CSV through this exercise.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Not clear. Please explain in more detail and give the expected output in your initial question.

Comment: I just updated the post. hopefully i explained my question better.